# What does IDS (Intrusion Detection System) exactly? What happens if I disable it?

Tags: permissions, security

One of my clients sends emails with click-through links. And sometimes, after clicking on the link, the following message is displayed.[image]

I did some research. The error is generated from a piece of code that does an IDS check. IDS stands for Intruder Detection System. It can be disabled in Drupal 7 by granting the skip IDS check to the anonymous user.

[image]

Now I have a workaround, but comment of the grants says *this permission has security implications*

What are exactly this security implications? Clients are always reluctant in disabling security stuff.

The work for IDS is done by the PHP package PHPIDS. It can be found on GitHub https://github.com/PHPIDS/PHPIDS. I could not find any documentation about how it works. The stats show me the following.

- The project is a bit old. Last commit in 2014.
- The project was also popular - 224 forks.

So maybe the IDS solves a problem from a long time ago and is not needed any more. Does someone (with a good memory) know the answers?

Answer (score 1):

It still has a use and does catch some attacks, but it does sometimes give false positives for civi (e.g. copy/pasting a long email thread into an activity is the one I usually see), and yes is very old. Some firewalls have traffic analysis that can be an alternative, or if you have access you could install an alternative IDS like [Snort](https://www.snort.org).

Comment: The good thing about Snort is that it has documentation